# Scalable application for increased parallel performance

Tags: .net, task-parallel-library

I have a list of 100,000 users, I get related data for these users from various web source (REST API) by passing the user's ID.

I first divided the 100,000 users into chunk(s) and then was calling the API's in parallel to get the data, below is the snippet.

```
ParallelOptions po = new ParallelOptions
    {
        po.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = -1;
    };


Parallel.ForEach(listSubscriberEmail, po, (subscriber) =>
    {    
        ProcessEachSubscriber(subscriber);
    });
```

`listSubscriberEmail` is a list of users and method `ProcessEachSubscriber` calls various APIs.

This was taking around 1 hour on a 4-core machine.

I migrated my codebase to an 8-core machine, but the time taken is still the same.

I suppose the way I have written the code should basically reduce the time, because ideally it should now spawn 8 tasks on on 8 cores... any ideas why this might not be the case?

Comment: It depends on what you're actually doing. Show us ProcessEachSubscriber. If it's not CPU bound, adding more cores shouldn't improve anything.

Comment: by the (limited) information that you have provided the bottleneck does not seem to be cpu. you are firing ~1.5k hits per second to some rest server over the network. either network is saturated or the rest server. also note that gain is never linear to additional cpu.

Comment: Since this would appear to be an IO bound operation, you could potentially find improvements by leveraging the Async/Await features such that IO waits would relinquish their threads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are going in the right direction.
First, I would not set `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` unlimited. This might starve your thread pool and set off hundreds of threads doing very little.
A common approach is to set the parrallelism to your number of cores:

```
ParallelOptions loopOptions = new ParallelOptions
{
    MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount,
};
```

and you can pass those options into a `Parallel.For` overload.

Second, you mention you get the user data from a REST API.
Presumably, this is a network call, so you have two items to consider:

1) There is a system default number of network connections that will be allowed in parallel, and this default is small (two or four I think). You can override this by calling:

```
ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = n;
```

anywhere in your process (ServicePointManager is one of those 'ambient context' interfaces that knows what it is supposed to do.)

'**n**' in this case takes some experimentation to see both how much network bandwidth is optimal for your application, as well as how well your REST api responds. (Just to give you an idea, I have a similar process with this set to 16, but I am calling a public REST api that is probably very robust and meant to scale very well.)

2) Take advantage of the new `async` methods in `WebClient` so that your parallel threads can be released to do other work while waiting on network I/O. As *I3arnon* said, network I/O is not CPU bound, so throwing extra cores at it will not make any difference.

Finally, as with any performance optimization, add some logging that accurately measures time of individual operations and see where your bottleneck is. You will often be surprised. Focus on those points before throwing massive parallel calls at it.